# fill details inside checked checkbox

Tags: javascript, php, html, checkbox

when I checked any checkbox , then it should gives a error message for all details whatever inside checked checkbox. In my code if I select 1st checkbox then it shows one textbox and one dropdown list, wants to do validation to fill textbox and dropdown list value, until it don't check another options ,& same with all checkbox. Rightnow I just take textbox and dropdown list for only 1st checkbox but it is for every checkbox. 
In simple words, unless i don't fill textbox value and dropdown value, it does not allow to check next option.
 I don't know to do. can anyone please tell me how to do this.

```
<script>
function validate()
{
    document.getElementById("error").innerHTML="atleast check one checkbox.";
    //alert("");
    var chk=document.getElementsByName("chkbox");
    var hasChecked = false;
    for(var i=0; i<chk.length; i++)
        {
            if(chk[i].checked)
            { 
                hasChecked= true;

                break;
            }
        }
return true;
}

function toggle(source) {
  checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('a[]');
  for(var i=0, n=checkboxes.length;i<n;i++) 
  {
    checkboxes[i].checked = source.checked;
  }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" name="form">
<table>
<tr><td><div id="error"></div></td></tr>
<tr><td style="padding:10px;padding-top:0; padding-bottom:0" >1 .What does the scope of test include?</td></tr>
<tr><td style="padding-left:5%;padding-bottom:0"><input type="checkbox" name="a[]" value="a) selected 1"> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;a)select 1<br /><br />
Name : <input type="text" name="fname"  /><br /><br />
Country : <select><option value="1">india</option><option value="2">usa</option></select>
</td></tr>
<tr><td style="padding-left:5%;padding-bottom:0"><input type="checkbox" name="a[]" value="b) selected 2"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;b)select 2</td></tr>
<tr><td style="padding-left:5%;padding-bottom:0"><input type="checkbox" name="a[]" value="c)selected 3"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;c select 3</td></tr>
<tr><td style="padding-left:5%;padding-bottom:0"><input type="checkbox" name="a[]" value="d)selected 4"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;d)select 4</td></tr>
<tr><td style="padding-left:5%;padding-bottom:0"><input type="checkbox" name="a[]" onClick="toggle(this)" value="e)Or all of the above"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;e)Or all of the above </td></tr>
</table>
<input type="submit" onclick="validate()" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{   
    $a=@$_POST['a'];

    $supplies = @implode(',',$_POST['a']);
    echo $supplies;
}


?>
```

Comment: Sorry it is too confusing,please describe  the exact problem

Comment: You've such big checkboxes, that you can show a textbox and a dropdown _inside a checkbox_ ?

Comment: I updated my question please check it. @Arunprasanth KV

Comment: what you mean by all values inside checked checkbox ?

Comment: Instead of focusing checkbox size, just read question & answer it. @ Teemu

Comment: all values mean the textbox field and dropdown list values are mandatory if I checked first checkbox @Arunprasanth KV

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is the solution:

```
<script>
function validate()
{
    var inputTags = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
    var checkboxCount = 0;
    for (var i=0, length = inputTags.length; i<length; i++) {
         if (inputTags[i].type == 'checkbox') {
            if(inputTags[i].checked){
                checkboxCount++;
            }    
         }
    }

    if(checkboxCount == 0){
        document.getElementById("error").innerHTML="atleast check one checkbox.";
        return false;
    }else{
        checkboxesahas = document.getElementsByClassName('aopt');        
        for(var i=0, n=checkboxesahas.length;i<n;i++)
        {
          if(checkboxesahas[i].checked){
              ahaselements = document.getElementsByClassName('ahaselement');
              for(var j=1;j<=ahaselements.length;j++) {
                ahaselementid = 'ahaselement'+j;
                if(document.getElementById(ahaselementid).value == ''){
                    document.getElementById("error").innerHTML="value missing in one or more of checked checkbox element.";
                    return false;                    
                }
              }
          }
        }        
    }
return true;
}

function toggle(source) {
  checkboxes = document.getElementsByClassName('aopt');
  for(var i=0, n=checkboxes.length;i<n;i++) 
  {
    checkboxes[i].checked = source.checked;
  }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" name="form">
<table>
<tr><td><div id="error"></div></td></tr>
<tr><td style="padding:10px;padding-top:0; padding-bottom:0" >1 .What does the scope of test include?</td></tr>
<tr><td style="padding-left:5%;padding-bottom:0"><input type="checkbox" name="a[]" class="aopt" value="a) selected 1"> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;a)select 1<br /><br />
Name : <input type="text" name="fname" id="ahaselement1" class="ahaselement" /><br /><br />
Country : <select name="country" id="ahaselement2" class="ahaselement"><option value="">no</option><option value="1">india</option><option value="2">usa</option></select>
</td></tr>
<tr><td style="padding-left:5%;padding-bottom:0"><input type="checkbox" name="a[]" class="aopt" value="b) selected 2"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;b)select 2</td></tr>
<tr><td style="padding-left:5%;padding-bottom:0"><input type="checkbox" name="a[]" class="aopt" value="c)selected 3"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;c select 3</td></tr>
<tr><td style="padding-left:5%;padding-bottom:0"><input type="checkbox" name="a[]" class="aopt" value="d)selected 4"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;d)select 4</td></tr>
<tr><td style="padding-left:5%;padding-bottom:0"><input type="checkbox" name="a[]" class="aopt" onClick="toggle(this)" value="e)Or all of the above"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;e)Or all of the above </td></tr>
</table>
<input type="submit" onclick="return validate()" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $a=@$_POST['a'];

    $supplies = @implode(',',$_POST['a']);
    echo $supplies;
}


?>
```

**PS** : I have filled validation in `error` id via innerHTML same way as you did. Also there are some changes made in checkboxes and other elements. Please check that also.

Let me know if there is any issue. Thank You! :)